# Access to props of a component from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, mobx

I'm learning react with mobx for state management and recently came across a scenario wherein i might have to deal with a function which could update the props of a react component.
The function is not part of the said component and that function is being exposed via the bootstrap js entry to let any external module access same and initiate re-rendering of the Component.
I'm unable to do so currently due to me being new to react js, Please suggest if it is feasible to do so in react , appreciate the help.

I've tried a few options however to no avail, i couldn't access the props of this component

```
PropTypes.instanceOf(SampleComponent).isRequired
```

Below is a sample component of mine

```
@observer
class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    .......
    }

    state = {
        ........
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        ..........
    }

    componentDidCatch(err) {
        ..........
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        .........
    }


    render() {
    .............
    }

SampleComponent.propTypes = {
    sampleProp: PropTypes.bool,
};

SampleComponent.defaultProps = {
    sampleProp: false,
};

function updateSampleProp(value) {
    ?????
}

export default injectIntl(SampleComponent);
export { updateSampleProp }
```

Comment: You need to place the function inside your component. Right now it looks like it's placed outside.

Comment: If i keep the function inside i'm not able to access that function in any external module, i end up fetching only constructor of this module using bootstrap and am unable to expose any function of the Component at this point

Comment: Then if you want to update the props, you need to update the actual props you are using on your component tag. It isn't meant to be updated through methods like that.

Comment: Props are read-only.   It's a little unclear what your trying to do,.  Could you maybe explain more details on what problem your trying to solve.

Comment: Yes Keith, I intend to cover a scenario wherein i'm able to update props of a component from an external module.
I have access to the default SampleComponent from the said external module with the help of bootstrap, however i do not have access to the props of it, thus i thought of exporting a function which could help me with access of props to re render

Comment: Or if i could somehow access props or functions of the SampleComponent that also solves the problem. I could fetch WrappedComponent but any further functions(apart from react lifecycle ones) on it weren't feasible.

Comment: Props are not something you update,.. Normally if props change it's the parent component performs some sort of state change that cause it's children to re-render, at this point props are used.   State is something that can change during a component lifecycle, but it's not something that's exposed by default.   But you could maybe use a `forwardRef` to expose a function to update state, that will then cause a re-render.